# Embeded SSRS report in mvc.net shows on all browsers except IE. How to show in IE?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, reporting-services

I have learned that MVC.NET does not support embedding an SSRS report in the view pages.

Not wanting to follow complicated tutorials on mixing web forms old technology and mvc.net, I found 2 other alternatives:

1. using an IFRAME
2. using an  tag

Code:

```
<div class="reports">    
    <iframe src="http://user:password@10.10.139.110/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fResearchers&rs:Command=Render"></iframe> 
</div>
```

And

```
<div class="reports"> 
    <object class="reportsObject" type="text/html"      data="http://user:password@10.10.139.110/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fResearchers&rs:Command=Render">
    </object>
</div>
```

The problem is that my report shows up when i use FF and CHROME but is not shown (and not even queried, after checking in fiddler) in IE (all versions from 10 to 7 with or without compatibility mode)

Note that when i directly open in IE the URL for the report:

```
http://user:password@10.10.139.110/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fResearchers&rs:Command=Render
```

It shows fine.

I also tried embedding without any DIVs just the iframe or object tags in the body, same result.

Here is the fiddler output showing that SSRS URL is not even called in IE:

[image: fiddler output]

Can anyone help here please ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem:

1. need to remove the 'user:password' from the src
2. the whole URL was accessed in my code through a parameter ( @Html.Raw(parm) ) and razor url encoded the '&' in 'Researchers&rs' and turned it into

```html
Researchers&amp;rs
```

Turns out IE can't eat that when embedding...

Note that after everything was fixed I found a new problem where only in IE the rendered report was not spread out correctly horizontally.

It is a known MS problem:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/37162582-9948-4696-b3f6-424b4d658fe0/sql-server-reporting-services-2008-version-internet-explorer-10011-con-iframes-problema-de?forum=repdeves